# How do I sort a C# SQL Server database programmatically and display each item as a separate button?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am working on a database C# project. I am using the a SQL Server database with a few tables I created. I am working on trying to get it so that I can hard code a function to sort the database by name alphabetically and still keep the ids to increment by 1's. At the moment the first is correct, but the rest are still the same name.

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::Cookbook_Project.Properties.Settings.Default.RecipesDatabaseConnectionString);

try
{
    cn.Open();

    var command = new SqlCommand("Select * from SoupTable", cn);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    command.CommandText = "Select soups from SoupTable Order By soups ASC";
    btnSoup1.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    command.CommandText = "Select soups from SoupTable Order By soups ASC";
    btnSoup2.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    command.CommandText = "Select soups from SoupTable Order By soups ASC";
    btnSoup3.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    command.CommandText = "Select soups from SoupTable Order By soups ASC";
    btnSoup4.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
}
finally
{
    cn.Close();
}
```

This is the code for connecting to the database and attempting to sort.

This is the data view of the table in the database with ids also sorted (I used the sort function here, not what I want)

[Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQzb1.png)

Design view of the table:

[Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItlEe.png)

Comment: Look up `ExecuteReader()`

Comment: In any RDBMS, the data is stored as **inherently unordered sets** of data. You **cannot** "sort the table" and persist that sort order in any way - the **only** way to get back data in a reliably sorted fashion is to `SELECT` from that table and explicitly define an `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute your SQL once using a DataReader, like this:

```
List<string> SoupList = new List<string();
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select soups from SoupTable Order By soups ASC", cn))
{   
    using (SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            SoupList.Add(Convert.ToString(myReader["soups"].ToString()));
        }    
    }
}
```

Now SoupList contains all your records.

Edit:  Updated to use Convert.ToString() as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Just an improvement use `Convert.ToString()` in place of '.ToString()` to handle conversion error when `null` values in the table.